# Combining Table and Views to Create Reports - Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala, looker

I have a scenario for which i need some guidance.

There is a report being created in Looker tool by utilizing 3 separate tables. Looker uses an Impala connection.

Now we have a client who do not have their data on these tables but would like to have a report created similar to the one we already
create using the 3 tables. This client will provide the data required for creation of reports on a single file.

How can i integrate this data onto the existing report.

The path we are planning is as below. I am not sure if thats the correct way to do.

1. Have the new client file uploaded onto a table.
2. Have views created corresponding to the 3 tables we use in creation of reports.
3. Join the table and Views. But here we cannot join them on column as the data is not for same client.
   Hence we think we can have UNION command between the table and view on our query.
4. With this we think, we can have the new client data also on our existing reports.

Can someone please take a look and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah a union is going to be the way to go here, assuming the data provided by the new client will have the same fields.  You can pull this into a derived table like so:

```
view: unioned_client_data {
  derived_table: {
    sql: SELECT 'client 1' AS client_name, * FROM client_1_table
         UNION
         SELECT 'cleint 2' AS client_name, * FROM client_2_table ;;
  }
  # dimensions, measures, etc
}
```

Once this is accomplished, you can filter your reports on this `client_name` field